# How can I automatically dismiss Alarms & Clock alarms after a specified amount of time?

Tags: windows, automation, alarm

*First of all, I would like to say that I am new to this site.  I have [an account on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/u/14469685/), so I understand the rules, but if my question is missing something important or anything else is wrong with it then please comment.  I'll try to fix the problems.*

OK, now to the actual question.  I have set up alarms in Alarms & Clock to go off every hour, for example at 8 AM, then another at 9 AM, then 10 AM, and so on.  Sometimes I need to go somewhere or do something for a long time, and I return noticing that the alarm from an hour ago is still going!

I want it so that the alarms themselves turn off after some time, say 2 minutes.  I tried looking around the app (Alarms & Clock) but didn't find any option for it.  Searching on the internet didn't work either.

I would say that I am good enough at programming to set up a custom solution.  I could use [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) + Task Manager to make a task to ring for some time, or maybe use [pyautogui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyautogui) somehow to click the dismiss button (if that doesn't make sense, you can ignore it).

I would prefer a built-in solution, but if there isn't one then I can make something for it.

**How would I be able to create an alarm that turns off after a certain amount of time?**